# Playing a MP3 File from a chosen Directory

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to play a song from a folder that a user selects. Essentially, I am using my own Queue that I've created and I'm getting the right path.

Within the code below, I am using a Var called path. The path is "C:\Users\Shaun\Downloads\TestMusic\Ed Sheeran - Shape of You.mp3". When I define the path as just, "Ed Sheeran - Shape of You.mp3". It works! This tells me that this looks into the directory of where the project is started or runned from.

So, how do I make it play a file from any given directory?

The 'path' I'm referring to is below, " public void handlecentreButtonClick()".

```
public class graphicalController implements Initializable 
{
    //GUI Decleration
    public Button centreButton;
    public Button backButton;
    public Button forwardButton;
    public ToggleButton muteToggle;
    public MenuItem loadFolder;

    //Controller Decleration
    String absolutePath;
    SongQueue q = new SongQueue();
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        centreButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Play_Button.png')");
        centreButton.setText("");

        backButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Back_Button.png')");
        backButton.setText("");

        forwardButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Forward_Button.png')");
        forwardButton.setText("");

        muteToggle.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/ToggleSound_Button.png')");
        muteToggle.setText("");
    }

    public void handlecentreButtonClick() {
        if(!(q.isEmpty())) {
            String file = q.peek().fileName.toString();
            String path = absolutePath + "\\" + file; 
            Media song = new Media(path);
            player = new MediaPlayer(song);
            player.play();
        }
    }

    public void handleforwardButtonClick() {
        System.out.println("Hello.");
        centreButton.setText("Hello");
    }

    public void handlebackButtonClick() {
        System.out.println("Hello.");
        centreButton.setText("Hello");
    }

    public void handleLoadButtonClick() {
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(null);
        absolutePath = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
        String path = absolutePath;
        loadFilesFromFolder(path);
    }

    public void loadFilesFromFolder(String path) {
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        while(!(q.isEmpty()))
        {
            try {Thread.sleep(500);}catch (Exception e){}
            Song j = q.pop();
        }
        int listLength = listOfFiles.length; 
        for (int k = 0; k < listLength; k++) {
            if (listOfFiles[k].isFile()) {
                String fileName = listOfFiles[k].getName();
                String fileNamePath = path + "\\" +fileName; 
                try {
                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fileNamePath));
                    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                    Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                    ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                    input.close();
                    String songName = metadata.get("title");
                    String artistName = metadata.get("xmpDM:artist");
                    String albumName = metadata.get("xmpDM:genre");
                    int id = k + 1;
                    Song newSong = new Song(id, fileName, songName, artistName, albumName);
                    q.push(newSong);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TikaException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }       
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Given a valid file path, you would create the appropriate URL representation with `new File(path).toURI().toString()`, i.e. you do `song = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());`. Obviously, using `path = absolutePath + '\\" + file ;` will choke badly on most file systems (basically anything except Windows).

Comment: Thank you James. It did work. Thanks for the tip as well! I can't believe it was that simple. I've been stuck on this for over an hour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Media song = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
```

I strongly recommend you construct the file in a platform independent way, however, instead of hard-coding a file separator specific to one particular file system. You can do

```
File path = new File(absolutePath, file);
Media song = new Media(path.toURI().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @James_D...

**You Cannot:**

Media song = new Media("C:\Users\Shaun\Downloads\TestMusic\Ed Sheeran - Shape of You.mp3");

This will try and find the directory from the point of where you've launched your program.

**Do:**

Media song = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

Comment: "This will try and find the directory from the point of where you've launched your program." is simply not true. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html) the constructor is expecting a URL (not a file at all), so it will fail because it tries to interpret `C:` as a URL scheme (and it is obviously not a valid scheme). If you provide no scheme, I believe it will look for a resource relative to the classpath (not the "point where you launched the program"), though the behavior is undocumented.